# Civilization 5 - Science victory vs. conquering the capital

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

So, an AI civ was on the verge of a science victory when I managed to conquer its capital. My question is: what happens now? Have I prevented a science victory for that Civ unless it takes back its capital? Does it just have to bring the one remaining part to its new capital? Or does it have to rebuild all the parts and bring them to its new capital?

What few hints I've found in Googling suggest things may have changed at some point, so just to be sure, this is with both G&K and BNW.

Comment: Although the possible dupe is from 2012 and thus before the release of BNW, I also can't find any notes that state that expansion changed the science victory in any significant way, other than adjusting a few tech costs.

Comment: At least assuming that there haven't been any changes in BNW, that answers my question. The only hint I'd had that something changed along the way was a passing comment by someone suggesting that taking the city no longer prevented a science win as of G&K, but it didn't give any details.

Answer (score 0):

I can find no evidence that any progress towards science victory is removed from a Civ.

The technology portion is obvious - no Civ ever loses a tech at any point in the game.  Whether or not spaceship parts are lost is a better question.  The parts once built and in transit could easily be destroyed, but once "assembled" on the launch pad they appear to count permanently towards victory.  The launchpad itself is just transferred to their new capital, with all existing parts intact.  Even though logically you would have likely destroyed their original launch pad, the game is only paying attention to the progress counters, and all those check is whether a part was delivered to a capital.

So yes, if the last part gets to the new capital (or is just built there), you're done, they win.